# Reading text and numeric data from .dat file in matlab

Tags: matlab, merging-data

Here i am sharing one of my data which are in .dat file. I have 16162 different files. I merged all into one file and want to read it in matlab and need to extract three parameter's values from a single file and arrange them in either row wise or column wise. I can do it by using C sharp codes but i want to do it by using matlab. can anybody help me out for writing the codes please?

Here is the one sample file data:

DISTRIBUTION: monomodal log-normal
 n    :  1.000
 r_mod:   .010
 sigma:  1.400

number conc., surface. conc., volume conc. 
  (cm^-3)       (mu^2cm^-3)      (mu^3cm^-3)
  .1087E+01     .1866E-02       .7878E-05

part. ave. radius, surf. ave. radius, vol. ave. radius : 
  .1149E-01   .1169E-01   .1201E-01

surface mean radius, volume mean radius : 
  .1267E-01   .1392E-01

eff. variance : 
  .9939E-01

Let's say: I want to extract or read three parameters (r_mod, sigma, Surface means radius). The corresponding values for these three parameters from the file I put in this page is .010 , 1.400 , .1267E-01

The output should be (Which i want):

```
r_mod   sigma   surface mean radius 
.01     1.4        1.27E-02 
.02     1.4        2.67E-02 
.03     1.4        3.98E-02 
...     ..           .. ..  
..       ..         .. ..
```

I have more than thousands similar files in a same directory. I want to read all those files in matlab and the output should show in this way in a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your files are strictly identical except for the numerical values you could try to use the Matlab function [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) and specify the format of each line.

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
fid=fopen('text.dat','r');
format={'DISTRIBUTION: monomodal log-normal n : %f r_mod: %f sigma: %f'; ...
        'number conc., surface. conc., volume conc. (cm^-3) (mu^2cm^-3) (mu^3cm^-3) %f %f %f'; ...
        'part. ave. radius, surf. ave. radius, vol. ave. radius : %f %f %f'; ...
        'surface mean radius, volume mean radius : %f %f'; ...
        'eff. variance : %f'};
data=cell(numel(format),1);
for i=1:numel(format)
    data{i}=textscan(fid,format{i},1);
end
fclose(fid);
```

In this example you can access the numerical values in the cell array `data`, r_mod is `data{1}{2}`, sigma is `data{1}{3}` and Surface means radius is `data{4}{1}` and so on. Then it is only a matter of organizing these data and saving the collection to file using `fprintf` to write the headers and [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html) to append the data.

Comment: Hi, Aabaz. Thank you very much for the codes and explanation.